# Redirect on successful login with FirebaseUI + React Router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I'm using the [FirebaseUI React](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) package for user sign in/up.
I have everything working except I can't get the redirect after successful sign in to work.

- The `StyledFirebaseAuth` is rendered as a component of my `SignIn`
  component that configures the FirebaseUI Auth model.
- The `SignIn` component is wrapped with `withRouter` so that when I receive the   success callback I can access the `history` prop and set to '/'
- I'm certain the sign in is successful as I see both the `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback and my `onAuthStateChanged` listener firing with a positive result.

EDIT: Seems problem is happening with email/password provider but when using Google as sign in provider the redirect works properly.

What am I doing wrong? this is the full file:

```js
import React from "react";

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import firebaseApp from '../firebaseApp';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';

import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// Styles
import styles from '../App.css'; // This uses CSS modules.

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'redirect',
    signInOptions: [      
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,      
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult, redirectUrl) => {
        console.log('signInSuccessWithAuthResult', authResult, redirectUrl);
        this.props.history.push('/');
        return false
      }
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Caazam SignIn</h1>
        <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebaseApp.auth()} />        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Comment: Does url change in the browser but the view isn't updating?

Comment: No, url doesn't change in browser.

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No errors in console. I'm thinking it has something to do with the default redirect logic in firebaseui (that I don't want to use as I'm not looking for a full page redirect) but can't figure it out.

Comment: OK, just noticed it is working when I choose Google as the sign in provider but doesn't work when I choose email/password as the provider. Will update the question.

Comment: Some more digging in: Seems my problem is caused by the async sequence of `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback and `onAuthStateChanged` listener. When using google provider the sequence is: callback, listener, callback again. When email/password: callback then listener. What's happening is that the redirect is actually working but because my main app auth listener isn't "authenticated" it routes right back to the signin. From user perspective its as if they stayed on sign in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem eventually was with the conditional routing in the main App component.

As I mentioned in the comments to the question there was an async race condition between the redirect (occurring 1st) in the SignIn component and the `onAuthStateChanged` listener in the App component (occurring later). When the redirect is made the listener hasn't changed state yet so the conditional route to '/' is redirected back to SignIn.

The solution I found is based on the great tutorial by Robin Wieruch - [A Complete Firebase in React Authentication Tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/). Definitly most comprehensive tutorial I found - simply swapped in FirebaseUI for 'standard' Firebase auth.

Basically instead of using conditional routing it uses two separate higher order components for authentication (passing auth state as react context to the whole app) and authorisation (protecting components and redirecting users to sign in when needed).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a PrivateRoute component as described in the react-router website:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Here's a tutorial from Tyler McGinnis for more detail:
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/